# msdev batch compile a C# project

Tags: c#, batch-file, compilation, command

I have downloaded the C# 2000 express edition and made a project.

I can compile this project from the command prompt like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\vcsexpress.exe" myProj.sln /build
```

My question is, is there a more "platform/IDE" independed way of doing this ?

Like this

```
msbuild myProj.sln /build
```

Where msbuild is some fantastic microsoft windows built in tool that, not only find out that it is a C# project but also find the right compiler as well and start it.

/Stefan

Comment: use visual studio express?

Comment: A Google search for `msbuild` would have showed that indeed, MSBuild actually exists and it'll do most of the things you want (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) - the strange/sad thing is that you'll have to jump through some hoops to find MSBuild itself (since each version of the .NET Framework has its own MSBuild).

Comment: C# 2000?! What's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MvanGeest got me on right track

It actually exist a msbuild in the 
    "c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild"

It do even more than expected, if there are no arguments to msbuild, it will search current library for project files (such as a .sln) and run it

Answer (score 0):

Locate you msbuild, usually C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (or whatever version you have). From command-line cd into it and then run desired solution provided correct path to the project.

```
msbuild myProj.sln /build
```

Here is [msbuild command-line reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx)